# Using a shell variable with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a list of tokens in a text file and want to use grep to get the lines from a second text file that contain those tokens, but seem to be having trouble accessing the shell variable with grep:

```
for n in `cat ./pos/1.txt`
do
cat dictionary.txt | grep "$n"
done
```

I've tried $n, "$n", ${n}, "${n}", ^${n}, and "^${n}" None of them seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you try this? `grep "$n" dictionary.txt`

Comment: I guess that your whole thing would be better written as `grep -f pos/1.txt dictionary.txt`.

Comment: This question was cross-posted at Unix+Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233714/using-a-shell-variable-with-grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping over the lines, it would be better to use the `-f` flag of `grep`:

```
grep -f pos/1.txt dictionary.txt
```

This will print the lines of `dictionary.txt` that match the patterns in `pos/1.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following is what you are looking for:

```
for n in `cat 1.txt`
do
grep $n dictionary.txt
done
```